# Startup scripts in GCP deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm deploying a VM instance using GCP deployment manager. There are some initialization actions which should be executed over deployment process.
I have imported a startup script and added the `metadata-from-file` property following this example: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/metadata_from_file/jinja/config.yaml

But I don't see those actions getting executed. Any other way to have such scripts included in the deployment plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startup script file execute a file **present in the vm** at startup. If you deploy your VM with deployment manager, your VM is new. Thus the file has to already exists in the boot image. 
Are you using a custom image?

If not, I recommend you to use startup script url and specify the startup file  stored in Google storage. Be sure that the compute engine has enough right to read the file.
More detail on compute engine startup script here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to take a look at [the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190708205213/https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/setting-metadata-and-startup-scripts) about setting the startup scripts within deployment manager. It states to set the metadata with different format, give it a try it should work.

```
metadata:
     items:
     - key: startup-script
       value: "STARTUP-SCRIPT-CONTENTS"
```

If you still have problems, please share the YAML of your deployment here without sensitive information and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't find that page.

Comment: Updated link with one from the Internet Archive

Comment: Can we add multiline values in start-up script in the json ?